# State of Thread before start of run is not New, its runnable, Isn't it wrong

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads in Java from the basic learning I understand that when a thread is created, it is in the new state. The thread has not yet started to run when the thread is in this state

```
public class MainClassForThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread t1 = new ExtendingThreadClass();
        Thread t2 = new ExtendingThreadClass();
        Thread t3 = new ExtendingThreadClass();

        System.out.println("Before start of thread the state of thread is " + t1.currentThread().getState());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

}

package Threads;

public class ExtendingThreadClass extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread running : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running for value of i " + i);
            System.out.println("State " + Thread.currentThread().getState());
        }
    }

}
```

I am expecting the output of the first line of code should be NEW as the thread t1 is not started yet, but Output is as below

```
Before start of thread the state of thread is RUNNABLE
Thread running : 10
Thread running : 12
Thread Thread-2 is running for value of i 0
Thread running : 11
Thread Thread-0 is running for value of i 0
State RUNNABLE
Thread Thread-0 is running for value of i 1
State RUNNABLE
Thread Thread-0 is running for value of i 2
```

Comment: You get the state of the current thread, which is running. Obviously.

Comment: If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--), it says "*Returns a reference to the **currently executing thread** object*", so why are you confused that the thread is running, when the method is explicitly documented to return a reference to an *executing* aka *running* thread?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
System.out.println("Before start of thread the state of thread is " + t1.currentThread().getState());
```

You get the current thread, and the current thread is running.

You probably don't want to get the state of the current thread, so change that line to

```
System.out.println("Before start of thread the state of thread is " + t1.getState());
```

Comment: More generally, pay attention to warnings and never call static methods from an instance.

Comment: @shmosel You're assuming that OP is using an IDE to even see the warning.